# Disable new line formatting in SCSS

Tags: css, netbeans, format

Since probably version 13 or 14 Netbeans is forcing new line after every property so:

```css
#nav { @include flex; flex-wrap: nowrap; align-items: stretch; flex: 1; }
```

becomes

```css
#nav {
    @include flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex: 1;
}
```

> Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting

has only Tabs And Indents option for CSS

Is there any way to disable new lines in formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue in NetBeans 15, but cannot resolve it. As you point out, NetBeans is hellbent on only allowing one CSS property per line when you format, regardless of how you configure your CSS settings. That must be intensely annoying.

You are not the only person to want to retain multiple CSS properties on a single line. See item #6 on Jira Bug Report [NETBEANS-4605
Advanced CSS (LESS, SASS) formatting options](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4605) which requests the following GUI enhancement to be able to achieve what you want:

[image: NETBEANS-4605 enhancement]

Unfortunately that bug is still OPEN and *Unasssigned*, and for some reason does not seem to exist on [the current NetBeans bug reporting system on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues?q=is%3Aissue+CSS+).

All I can suggest is that you additionally raise a NetBeans Bug Report on GitHub specifically for this issue, citing the affected version(s) of NetBeans and the most recent version of NetBeans that was unaffected (if possible). I confirm that it is a problem on NetBeans 15.

Also, since multiple CSS properties on a single line used to be possible, be sure to present the issue as a bug (i.e. existing functionality became broken), rather than merely a feature request as shown in the screen shot above. I'm guessing that approach may result in your bug report getting higher priority.